# How to call on to alphabetize objects in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, alphabetical-sort

I'm trying to write a method that receives an `ArrayList` of `Strings` and puts it into alphabetical order. Is it possible to use the sort method for strings and not `ints`?

This is different from the other question because the way he did it is much more complicated than I'm aiming for. I just wanted a line of code rather than a whole block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure what are you trying to say by

> not int s

But if you want to sort A arraylist of string alphabetically, this can be a way.

```
java.util.Collections.sort(arrayListOfString);
```

Comment: Sorry it was originally `ints` but someone edited it to be `int` s